# Saltstack -> 'Pillar failed to render with the following messages'

Tags: salt-stack

On my FreeBSD I have a file *packages.sls* in the following path */usr/local/etc/salt/states*
I'm getting the following error message when i do `salt '*' state.apply packages` :

```
freebsd:
   Data failed to compile:
----------
   Pillar failed to render with the following messages:
----------
   Rendering SLS 'config' failed. Please see master log for details.
```

On the file master log i have the following details:

```
2022-06-02 10:05:12,222 [salt.roster                                                        :104 ][ERROR   ][3425] Can't access roster for backend flat: Roster file "/usr/local/etc/salt/roster" not found
2022-06-02 10:05:12,434 [salt.pillar                                                        :900 ][CRITICAL][3427] Rendering SLS 'config' failed, render error:
found unexpected end of stream
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/salt/renderers/yaml.py", line 62, in render
    data = yamlloader.load(yaml_data, Loader=get_yaml_loader(argline))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/salt/utils/yamlloader.py", line 169, in load
    return yaml.load(stream, Loader=Loader)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 114, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 49, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "yaml/_yaml.pyx", line 707, in yaml._yaml.CParser.get_single_node
  File "yaml/_yaml.pyx", line 725, in yaml._yaml.CParser._compose_document
  File "yaml/_yaml.pyx", line 776, in yaml._yaml.CParser._compose_node
  File "yaml/_yaml.pyx", line 890, in yaml._yaml.CParser._compose_mapping_node
  File "yaml/_yaml.pyx", line 776, in yaml._yaml.CParser._compose_node
  File "yaml/_yaml.pyx", line 892, in yaml._yaml.CParser._compose_mapping_node
  File "yaml/_yaml.pyx", line 905, in yaml._yaml.CParser._parse_next_event
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a quoted scalar
  in "<unicode string>", line 3, column 27
found unexpected end of stream
  in "<unicode string>", line 4, column 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/salt/pillar/__init__.py", line 887, in render_pstate
    state = compile_template(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/salt/template.py", line 99, in compile_template
    ret = render(input_data, saltenv, sls, **render_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 149, in __call__
    return self.loader.run(run_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 1201, in run
    return self._last_context.run(self._run_as, _func_or_method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 1216, in _run_as
    return _func_or_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/salt/renderers/yaml.py", line 66, in render
    raise SaltRenderError(err_type, line_num, exc.problem_mark.buffer)
salt.exceptions.SaltRenderError: found unexpected end of stream
2022-06-02 10:05:12,435 [salt.pillar                                                        :1224][CRITICAL][3427] Pillar render error: Rendering SLS 'config' failed. Please see master log for details.
```

My sls file packages.sls

```
install_bash:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - bash
      - vim
      - curl
```

Any idea on how to solve this situation?

Thank you

Comment: Hey, it seems like your sls-file is not valid yaml, could you maybe check the validity or add it to this post?

Comment: I have edited my post and added the sls file.

Comment: it is not your state we need. but the config pillar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem of DNS/Cache. Issue solved after changing the hostname in minion.id ,clear cache, accepted new key and restart.